# MacPorts is unusable

Tags: octave, macports

I've recently installed MacPorts as explained on MacPorts website. All the process went well. The .profile file in my home directory has been updated (in this file the paths "/opt/local/bin" and "/opt/local/sbin" are added to the environment variable PATH) and all the macports files are in the directory "/opt". When I type "which port" in the shell, it returns "/opt/local/bin/port".

But something weird happens when I ask to install the port "octave-devel" (I've installed MacPorts to use Octave on my Mac in the first place). So when I enter the command "sudo port install octave-devel +atlas+docs" (as explained in [GNU Octave wiki](http://wiki.octave.org/Octave_for_MacOS_X)) in the terminal and type my password, the shell replies "Error: Port octave-devel not found". However the port "octave-devel" seems to exist because I've found its description on [this page](https://trac.macports.org/browser/trunk/dports/math/octave-devel/Portfile) of the macports website.

Because I had to use Octave quickly I first wanted to uninstall MacPorts and install Fink instead and I tried the method described on the MacPorts website but after I typed "sudo port -fp uninstall installed" it returned "Error: No ports matched the given expression". I couldn't even uninstall this software! I really think that it is a problem of MacPorts itself and not the octave port but I can't find what exactly.

Eventually I used Octave on a Windows computer but it annoys me not to know what is wrong with MacPorts on my computer. And mainly, I want to be capable to use GNU Octave on my Mac because I need it for school.

Thank you in advance and happy holidays.

Comment: I've had much better luck with [homebrew](http://mxcl.github.com/homebrew/) than with any of the older package managers, e.g. fink, MacPorts, etc.

Comment: Thanks! But I would like to (at least!) manage to uninstall MacPorts before. The best would be to be able to make MacPorts work.

Comment: Well FWIW I'm using octave on Mac OS X here as installed by homebrew and it works fine. I would suggest deleting MacPorts, installing homebrew and then `brew install octave`...

Comment: Ok then. But how can I uninstall properly MacPorts?

Comment: See: http://guide.macports.org/chunked/installing.macports.uninstalling.html

Comment: Yes I've seen this page. Like I said in my first post:
"...but after I typed "sudo port -fp uninstall installed" it returned "Error: No ports matched the given expression"..."
It is not working and I don't know why...

Comment: That probably just means you have no ports installed. If that's the case then just proceed with the second step.

Comment: Ok it is done. But it is weird, I had nothing about MacPorts in the directory "/Applications"...
It left an empty "/opt" directory, can I delete it?
I am gonna install Homebrew now. Thanks again!

Comment: Yes - you can delete /opt

Comment: I couldn't do it before yesterday, but I installed it via Homebrew and it seems to work well. Thanks!

Comment: Great - it works well for me too - I have had some issues with graph plotting but the actual core Octave stuff seems to work pretty well.

Comment: Yes, I wanted to talk about his actually. I've made some tests and I don't know why I can't plot anything... In fact I believed that I found why and I installed gnuplot via Homebrew but again it is not working... If I try to plot a vector x, I have this:
"octave:2> plot(x)

gnuplot> set terminal aqua enhanced title "Figure 1" size 560 420  font "*,6"
                      ^
         line 0: unknown or ambiguous terminal type; type just 'set terminal' for a list"

Comment: i can't remember exactly what I did to make this work, but I do remember that I installed AquaTerm.

Comment: Do you have a link? I have already searched for one but it is contradictory...

Comment: The horse's mouth: http://aquaterm.sourceforge.net

Comment: Okay I found a way to make octave plot without installing AquaTerm. You just need to set the environment variable GNUTERM as x11 (or aqua if installed) by invoking: "setenv("GNUTERM", "x11")" before you try to plot anything... But I admit that it is the plots look better with AquaTerm than gnuplot now that I've tried both. And I think that once you have installed AquaTerm (at least before installing gnuplot like I did) you don't need to fix the variable GNUPLOT to "aqua", to use AquaTerm... Thanks again for your patience.

Comment: No problem - glad you got it working.

Comment: this is not a question for SO, you should post this here http://apple.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure which version of OSX you are running, however, I have octave (not octave-devel) version 3.6.4 installed via macports on a machine running OSX 10.9.1.  This was built using:

sudo port install octave

which yields a known bug building the atlas dependency that results from a missing fortran compiler.  At this point you have two options.  Before attempting to install octave first try to install atlas separately, either overriding the standard clang compiler with the gcc4x flag, or install atlas using:

sudo port install atlas +nofortran

which runs fine using clang.  With atlas installed, octave should build to completion although there is a possibility that you will find an error regarding the use of arpack by apple as a vector library.  Using +arpack is preferred, so it may be useful to load this by hand as well before starting your octave install.

Answer (score 1):

Trying to install Octave using MacPorts I ran into a similar problem.

**Summary**

My solution was to first clean & build atlas separately using gcc47 instead of the default mpclang34. Then to build the default octave.

**Details**

This is on a MacBook running an older OS (10.7.5), the standard Octave (3.8.2) package failed to build - it hung on building the atlas dependency.

Solution:

```
sudo port clean atlas
sudo port -v install atlas +gcc48
sudo port -v install octave +atlas+docs
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm currently going through the process of installing Octave via MacPorts. I used the following command which I found on Shifteleven.com:

```
sudo port install octave-devel +gcc45
```

It seems to be working so far. You also need to make sure you've installed the Xcode command line tools, which is something that I forgot to do the first time I tried.

Answer (score 0):

I also ran into problems installing Octave using Macports on OSX 10.10.1 and solved them, similar to @Tom_N_PDX and @isak.

#### Short version

I got it working using one of the options described by @isak.

#### More detailed version

Running `sudo port install octave` failed because of the missing Fortran compiler problem.

I next installed Fortran using Macports `sudo port install gcc48` and then tried re-installing Octave

```
sudo port clean octave    
sudo port install octave
```

This "hung" on Atlas, as others have mentioned, although I now realize it just takes a long time and I killed it before it finished.  Likely it would have worked, as the output said it had found Fortran

> Selected C compiler: /usr/bin/clang
>
> Selected F77 compiler: gfortran48

I then installed atlas separately, using the `+gcc48` flag, as suggested by @isak

```
sudo port install atlas +gcc48
```

but it displayed the same compiler information as above (consistent with my conjecture that the above would have worked).  This process took about 4 hours.  You can monitor the progress of the task in the logfile (found with the command `sudo port logfile atlas`), which reassures you it's doing something and not "hung".  (Oddly the output does halt mid-message, but it always eventually resumed.  Also there were a lot of warning messages.)

Last, running the following worked:

```
sudo port clean octave
sudo port install +arpack
```

I actually first tried without the `+arpack` option and it worked but I got the following message, consistent with @isak's answer

> WARNING: Dependency 'arpack' is installed with the +accelerate variant, using   Apple's Vector Libraries which have some known bugs that can cause Octave to  crash if using certain functions in arpack.  The +atlas variant does not have  these issues with Octave, but does take many hours to compile even on modern  hardware.

When I reinstalled Octave with the `+arpack` flag it took less than a minute (because I had already installed Atlas).

Answer (score -1):

I had a similar problem with MacPorts. I would recommend using HomeBrew instead. Here are the commands to install Octave on HomeBrew:

```
/usr/bin/ruby -e "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/master/install)"

brew update

brew upgrade

brew install octave
```